Update Keyframes after Rotating Objects with Empty
Due to some scene management, I want to rotate my whole scene 180 degrees on the y or x axis. I created an empty, parented all the objects in my scene to it and rotated it 180 degrees. Now my Objects are correctly orientated but the keyframed objects such as the camera have retained the keyframes. Meaning, the camera is going up but the keyframes are still going from positive (1.4) to negative (-0.1). Is there any way to have the Objects update the keyframes so that the camera would have the keyframes -1.4 and 0.1 instead of 1.4 and -0,1?
As you can see in the picture, the camera is physically on the positive side of the Z axis but the keyframe has still the negative value of -0.1

I'm happy to provide any additional information
All the Best and thank you in advance

The keyframes are always relative to their frame of reference. If they are unparented, the frame of reference is the world's (global) orientation. As soon as you parent them, the keyframes are in relation to the new frame of reference, i.e. the parent's orientation (location, rotation and scale). The question is: as long as the objects are doing what they should, is it important that the values you see are relative to the global orientation instead of their local orientation? Or are you just wondering why they differ?

From what you commented under the answer which is now deleted: why don't you simply rotate the sky texture instead of the whole scene?

Answer to the first comment: I can absolutely work with the inverted controls but i would have preferred to work with the "correct" ones if there would have been an easy solution.

Answer to the second comment: You can't rotate the Nishita Sky Texture to my knowledge :D

My bad... doesn't have a Vector input, completely forgot about that. The only solution for that would be that you render a 360° equirectangular HDRI from the Nishita Sky Texture, then rotate it with Mapping node. Of course you cannot edit it anymore then... unless you render an animation with the sun traveling from lowest to highest Sun Elevation for sunrise and sunset... and for the Sun Rotation you could use the Mapping node. About the controls: well, unfortunately there is no solution I know of. Only in Edit Mode you can switch between Local and Global, which doesn't help.
